# How can I show photos that aren't in an album?

Tags: photos, photos.app

I am trying to organize all my photos in iPhoto. Is there a filter or setting that allows me to see all "unsorted" photos? ie photos that aren't in an album?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File → New Smart Album and set the condition to ‘Album is not Any’.

[image]

Media not in an album will appear in this new Smart Album.

Comment: You just changed the game for me. Thank you!